# How to use external libraries/projects in New project in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, open-source, libraries

I'm trying to learn ember.js . I'm not understanding how to add libraries or open source projects like embertable to a new project which I created in ember.js.

Basically, I need to have a better understanding of the flow. Can you please provide me with a video/document which explains how to deal with using other applications in a ember application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, you've already added libraries to your application --> `jQuery` and `Handlebars` are nothing but external libraries which you're loading as dependencies for running your `Ember` project.

if you want to start with `ember-table`, your best bet is to clone the github project, or download it from their homepage and start with this as a code base - `ember-table` is an already up and running ember project, as far as I know...